# How to create a live CD with your own applications?

Tags: livecd

I've been looking for creating my own live CD to restore backups and perhaps have some useful applications for example to rescue data in case of a virus or some system crash.

I've been experimenting with [WinPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) en [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), but I was guessing there were more advanced versions by now. I also found the [VistaPE](http://www.vistape.net/) version, since I think WinPE is based on Windows.

But now I need to find out where I can find how to add applications to these CDs or perhaps there is a way to make my own Linux Live CD.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linux, try [Reconstructor](http://www.reconstructor.org) to create your own Ubuntu live CD with programs of your choice:

> Reconstructor is a Live CD creator for Ubuntu Linux.
>
> It uses the Ubuntu Linux Live CD as a base, and then allows customization of boot screens (usplash), gnome settings, and software (you can also use the chroot environment to make other changes before creating the live cd).
>
> Reconstructor uses the solid Ubuntu foundation, and allows for extensive customization. For example, create a custom Live CD with blender, inkscape, etc. included for a friend in graphics, or simply use econstructor to re-brand your environment (wallpaper, fonts).

From what I have heard, it is dead simple. Just run

```
sudo python reconstructor.py
```

from the folder where you extracted it and follow the nice, pretty prompts. You will need either a live Ubuntu CD or an .iso for one.

Comment: Reconstructor seems no longer to exist

Comment: that link is linking to some weird welding site.

Answer (score 1):

[Build your own Linux LiveCD](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7246)

[LiveCD Creation Resources (Windows & Linux)](http://www.livecdlist.com/wiki/index.php/LiveCD_Creation_Resources)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own openSUSE/SLES/SLED remixes using [SUSE Studio](http://susestudio.com).