# How to create a boot CD

Tags: linux, windows-vista, software-rec, multi-boot, bootable-media

How to create a boot CD for a dual-booting system? Just consider I am having Windows and Ubuntu, [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) is the boot loader. I just want to create a dual-boot CD for the same operation.

Comment: What should the Boot CD do?

Comment: And does it have to be a CD or could you also use a USB stick?

Comment: anything is fine .. But i just want to creat the boot disk for dual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/7823/how-to-create-a-live-cd-with-your-own-applications) on LiveCD's. You could make one yourself, if that does what you need.

If you could also use a bootable USB stick (much easier than a CD perhaps), [look at this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1238/how-do-you-create-a-bootable-partition-on-a-usb-drive).

---

[Quoted](https://superuser.com/questions/7823/how-to-create-a-live-cd-with-your-own-applications/7826#7826) from Josh Hunt on [How to create a live CD with your own applications](https://superuser.com/questions/7823/how-to-create-a-live-cd-with-your-own-applications):

> For linux, try [Reconstructor](http://www.reconstructor.org) to create your own Ubuntu live CD with programs of your choice:
>
> > Reconstructor is a Live CD creator for Ubuntu Linux.
> >
> > It uses the Ubuntu Linux Live CD as a base, and then allows customization of boot screens (usplash), gnome settings, and software (you can also use the chroot environment to make other changes before creating the live cd).
> >
> > Reconstructor uses the solid Ubuntu foundation, and allows for extensive customization. For example, create a custom Live CD with blender, inkscape, etc. included for a friend in graphics, or simply use econstructor to re-brand your environment (wallpaper, fonts).
>
> From what I have heard, it is dead simple. Just run
>
> ```
> sudo python reconstructor.py
> ```
>
> from the folder where you extracted it and follow the nice, pretty prompts. You will need either a live Ubuntu CD or an .iso for one.

Comment: Oh how very nice of you :)

Comment: Never hurts to quote a good answer ;-)